# The app crashes and is not connecting to a Bluetooth-paired device on Android 12 and greater. But it works fine on Android version 11 devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have created an app to communicate with a Bluetooth module connected to an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino). The app works fine on [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11).

But when I run the app on [Android 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_13), at first the app crashes and the log shows Android permission Bluetooth connect is required, even though I have written code to ask for permission for Bluetooth connect and Bluetooth scan.

I'm only getting the popup to allow to find, connect to and determine the relative position of nearby devices and not any popup to turn on Bluetooth.

When I open the app again with Bluetooth turned on manually, the paired devices are shown and when tried to connect, app crashes again and error shows permission Bluetooth scan is required.
When I open the app again and try to connect, the error shows socket might closed or timed out

My manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
                     tools:targetApi="s" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
                  android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
                  android:required="true"/>
```

When the app is launched, the app crashes, showing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for android.content.AttributionSource@1954ea10: AdapterService getBondedDevices
at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:473)
at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkConnectPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:505)
at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder.getBondedDevices(AdapterService.java:2748)
at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder.getBondedDevices(AdapterService.java:2740)
```

When the app is opened the second time and tries to connect with a paired device, the error shows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.example.angelhand, PID: 30081
java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@4edec11c: AdapterService cancelDiscovery
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:473)
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkScanPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:532)
```

If I log the socket I get, android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@ff3109c.

Again when I open and try to connect, the error shows:

```
run:
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:815)
```

My activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RelativeLayout developer_btn;
    public ImageButton disconnect_btn, refresh_btn;
    private DeviceListAdapter deviceListAdapter;
    private List deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DeviceListModel deviceListModel;
    MyApp myApp;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    BluetoothDevice[] btArray;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> set_pairedDevices;
    BluetoothSocket bsocket;
    public TextView connect_status,no_device_msg;
    public RelativeLayout device_item, connect_layout;
    public boolean ble_connected = false;
    Object[] bondedObj;
    public static final int STATE_LISTENING = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED = 4;
    public static final int STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 5;
    public static final int STATE_MESSAGE_WRITE = 6;
    private final static int MESSAGE_READ = 7;
    public static final int ACTION_DEVICE_CONNECT = 1;
    public static final int ACTION_DEVICE_DISCONNECT = 2;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;

    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myApp = ((MyApp) getApplicationContext());
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        connect_layout = findViewById(R.id.connect_layout);
        developer_btn = findViewById(R.id.developer_btn);
        disconnect_btn = findViewById(R.id.disconnect_btn);
        refresh_btn = findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn);
        no_device_msg = findViewById(R.id.no_device_msg);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.device_list_recycler_view);
        deviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(deviceList, this, myApp);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);
        initBluetooth();
        no_device_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        disconnect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = null;
                deviceConnection(tv, null, 0, ACTION_DEVICE_DISCONNECT);

            }
        });
        refresh_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findPairedDevices();
            }
        });
        developer_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ble_connected) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeveloperActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(connect_layout,"Connect to a device", 500);
                    snackbar.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeveloperActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        deviceConnection(null, null, 0, ACTION_DEVICE_DISCONNECT);
    }

    private void initBluetooth() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100);
                    //findPairedDevices();
                }
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 31) {
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
            }
        } else {
            findPairedDevices();
        }
    }

    public void findPairedDevices() {
        no_device_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        deviceList.clear();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100);
            }
        }
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
            bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        } else {
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        }
        set_pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        Log.w(TAG, "findPairedDevices set_paired: " + set_pairedDevices);
        if (set_pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            no_device_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : set_pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress();
                bondedObj = set_pairedDevices.toArray();
                deviceListModel = new DeviceListModel(deviceName, deviceHardwareAddress);
                deviceList.add(deviceListModel);
                deviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        else{
            no_device_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            findPairedDevices();
        }
    }


    //Handler
    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case STATE_LISTENING:
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTING:
                    connect_status.setText("Connecting...");
                    connect_status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.device_connecting));
                    device_item.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.device_bg_active));
                    ble_connected = false;
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTED:
                    device_item.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.device_bg_connected));
                    connect_status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ok_green));
                    connect_status.setText("Connected");
                    ble_connected = true;
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED:
                    device_item.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.device_item_bg));
                    connect_status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_red));
                    connect_status.setText("Connection failed");
                    ble_connected = false;
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    String arduinoMsg = msg.obj.toString(); // Read message from Arduino
                    break;
                case STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                    byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String tmp_msg = new String(readBuff, 0, msg.arg1);
                    break;
                case STATE_MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100);
                    }
                }
- tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
            Log.w(TAG, "ConnectThread: "+mmSocket);
        }

        public void run() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 100);
                }
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_CONNECTING).sendToTarget();
                mmSocket.connect();
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_CONNECTED).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED).sendToTarget();
                Log.e(TAG, "run: ", connectException);
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }
            bsocket = mmSocket;
            myApp.setB_socket(bsocket);
            myApp.setB_device_address(mmDevice.getAddress());
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                myApp.setB_socket(null);
                myApp.setB_device_address("");
                myApp.setB_device_name("");
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    public void deviceConnection(TextView conn_status, RelativeLayout dev_item, int position, int actionCode){
        BluetoothSocket connectedSocket;
        connectedSocket = myApp.getB_socket();
        if(actionCode == ACTION_DEVICE_CONNECT){
            connect_status = conn_status;
            device_item = dev_item;
            if (connectedSocket == null){
                BluetoothSocket bs=null;
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) bondedObj[position];
                ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
                connectThread.start();
            }
            else{
                Log.w(TAG, "deviceConnection: Already connected" );
                connect_status.setText("Connected");
            }
        }
        else if(actionCode == ACTION_DEVICE_DISCONNECT){
            if (connectedSocket != null){
                try {
                    connectedSocket.close();
                    myApp.setB_socket(null);
                    myApp.setB_device_address("");
                    myApp.setB_device_name("");
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(connect_layout,"Disconnected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                    findPairedDevices();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ble_connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing my [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), but it didn't work. I also tried to create socket using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() method, but it didn't work either.

I don't know if it helps, but when I connect my phone (Android 13 which is having the said issue) to a Bluetooth headset and then when I try to connect to the desired paired device through the app, sometimes (only sometimes) the app gets connected and I'm able to send and receive data.

Is there another way to launch runtime permissions in Java?

Comment: There are permission changes from Android 12 in bluetooth permissions. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions.     
 Get permission at runtime

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#availability

Comment: I have permissions in manifest file but still not working

Comment: Adding in manifest is mandatory and asking runtime is also mandatory. If you just declare in manifest then android system wouldn't grant automatically. you have to request for permission.

Comment: In my activity code I used ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100); to get run time permission. Is this correct or is there any other way to get run time permission

Comment: "`- tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);`" seems unlikely to have been in the source code (it would seem to result in a compile error)